# Pass data from cloud firestore into a variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

it's posiblo to fetch data from cloud firestore into a variable in javascript?
I have two collections, the first one it's called  'chats' and have the documents 'created_at', 'messege' and 'username'.

and the second collection it's call 'users' and have only one document called 'username' which have inside the username that the user create in the signin.

so my idea it's pass the username from the collection 'users' to the 'username' from the collection 'chats' to use it in a class like this one

```js
class Chatroom {
  constructor(room, username) {
    this.room = room;
    this.username = username;
    this.chats = db.collection("chats");
  }
  async addChat(message) {
    const now = new Date();
    const chat = {
      message,
      username: this.username,
      room: this.room,
      created_at: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now),
    };
    const response = await this.chats.add(chat);
    return response;
  }
  getChats(callback) {
    this.chats.orderBy("created_at").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
          callback(change.doc.data());
        }
      });
    });
  }
  updateName(username) {
    this.username = username;
  }
}
```

I was thinking in doing somethin like this, because I did the same in another part of the code just to show the login info and it's work. But i don't get how to get that username data out of the functions to use it again in the class.

```js
let getTheuser = (user) => {
  if (user) {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        username = doc.data().username;
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to get a `username` through the `getTheuser()` function and use the resulting username to create an instance of the `Chatroom()` class.

You first need to return, in the `getTheuser()` function, the value you get through the Firestore query:

```
let getTheuser = (user) => {
  if (user) {
    return db.collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        return username = doc.data().username;
      });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Note that the `getTheuser()` function is asynchronous, therefore you need to either use `then()` or async/await. So the following should do the trick:

```
const myUser = ....; // an Object having a uid property
const myRoom = ...;

getTheuser(myUser)
.then(username => {
  if (username) {
    const myChatroom = new Chatroom(myRoom, username);
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Comment: I get the firs part, but in the second part I don't understand in which part of the class 'Chatroom' I have to put the code, because when the 'const' myUser and myRoom are created I don't know what value pass it

Comment: The second part shows how to get a username value and use it to create an instance of the class. You should not use it in the class. Or I have totally misunderstood your goal.

Comment: Hey @Alan, did you have time to look further at the proposed answer?

Comment: Hello @Renaud it's work!  sorry for the delay I was with some issues thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I know it does not answer directly your question but I think you need to think about how everything is connected.

This is how I would organize my workflow.

This is pseudo code and only a suggestion. It might not be the best but that's what I could of think right now.

```
class Room {
  constructor ({ id, name }) {
    this.id = id // || genId() // if no id is provided than generate a unique id
    this.name = name
    this.chat = []
  }

  static async getRooms () {
    // get rooms from database and instantiate data with Room class
  }

  async getChats () {
    // get room chat from database (filter with roomId)
    // dont forget to instantiate data with Chat class + assign list to this.chat array
  }

  listenForChats (cb) {
    // use onSnapshot on chat filter by roomId and return callback
  }
  
  sendChat (chat, user) {
    // set roomId, userId and use chat.create()
  }

  async create () {
    // check if not already in database
    // add to database
  }

  async destroy () {
    // remove from database
  }
}

class Chat {
  constructor ({ id, userId, roomId, message }) {
    this.id = id // || genId()
    this.user
  }

  async create () {
    // add to database
  }

  async destoy () {
    // remove from database
  }
}

class User {
  constructor ({ id, username }) {
    this.id = id // || genId()
    this.username = username
  }

  static async getAllUsers () {
    // get users from database and instantiate data with User class
  }

  static async getUser (id) {
    // get specific user from database and instantiate data with User class
  }

  async getChats () {
    // get chat of users from database
  }

  async create () {
    // check if not already in database
    // add to database auto assign id
  }

  async destroy () {
    // remove from database
  }
}

// Usage
const users = await User.getAllUsers()

const room = new Room({ name: 'test' })
await room.create()

const firstUser = users[0]

// Send message like this
const chat = new Chat({ userId: firstUser.id, roomId: room.id, message: 'hello' })
await chat.create()

// or
const chat = new Chat({ message: 'hello' })
room.sendChat(chat, firstUser)
```

Of course you can add more functions to your class for example: static async getRoom(id) and return the Room object instantiated with the data from the database.